# Вывод базы данных SQLite

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, вывод

Задание следующее:

> Нужно написать оболочку для базы данных SQLite, которая в консоли
> будет считывать запросы, и давать ответ: прошла запись или нет, а на
> SELECT сразу делать вывод данных на экран.

Код ниже. Выводится следующим образом: все Id 0, а имена пустые. Скорее всего, проблема именно в выводе, т.к. при выборе, например, конкретного имени, он выводит только одного кандидата (причем выводит неправильно). Подскажите, как правильно организовать вывод.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <QtSql/QSqlDatabase>
#include <QtSql/QSqlError>
#include <QtSql/QSqlQuery>
#include <QtSql/QSqlRecord>
#include <QVariant>



int main()
{
    QSqlDatabase myDb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    myDb.setDatabaseName("MyFirstDatabase.db");

    if(!myDb.open()){
        std::cout<< myDb.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
    }
    else{
        std::cout<<"Database is opened."<<std::endl << "To close the app, print \"exit\"" << std::endl;
        std::string requestString;      //Строковый запрос
        QSqlQuery query;
        do{
            std::cout << "Input a command:" << std::endl;
            getline(std::cin, requestString);

            QString QRequest = QString::fromStdString(requestString);  //Тот же запрос, но как QString

            if(requestString != "exit"){
                 query.exec(QRequest);

                 if(query.isActive() && requestString!="exit"){
                     std::cout << "Request succeded." << std::endl;
                 }
                 else{
                     std::cout << "Whoops, something went wrong! ERROR: " << query.lastError().text().toStdString() << std::endl;
                 }

                 if(query.isSelect()){
                    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();

                    for(int i = 0; i < rec.count(); i++){         //Вывод шапки таблицы
                        std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left);
                        std::cout << std::setw(10) << rec.fieldName(i).toStdString();
                    }
                    std::cout << std::endl;

                    while(query.next()){
                        std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left);
                        for(int j = 0; j < rec.count(); j++){
                            std::cout << std::setw(10) << rec.value(j).toString().toStdString();
                        }
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                    }
                 }
            }


        }while(requestString!="exit");
    }
    myDb.close();
    std::cout<<"Thanks for using database. All the best!"<<std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Не хватает `<string>`

Comment: @dIm0n спасибо за уточнение, но проблема была не в этом. Видимо Qt не ругается если его не подключить. Иначе у меня бы просто не запускалась программа)

Comment: В любом случае надо добавить, компилируется в текущем виде или нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело было в том, что за хранение значений кортежа отвечает не Record, а сама Query. Поэтому правильный вывод выглядит так:

```
while(query.next()){
    std::cout << std::setiosflags(std::ios::left);
    for(int j = 0; j < rec.count(); j++){
        std::cout << std::setw(10) 
        <<query.value(j).toString().toStdString();
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```